# Not able to remove extra star from pattern

Tags: python

I have pattern which I am trying to print

**Expected output :**

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 
1 * 2 * 3 
1 * 2 
1
```

I have written a code but not getting how to add this check so that last star should not be printed [ refer above expected output ]

```
n=5
l = [  str(i) + ' *'   for i in range(1,n+1) ]
for j in range(1,n+1):
  print(' '.join(l))
  del l[-1]
```

**My output :**

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 *
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 *
1 * 2 * 3 *
1 * 2 *
1 *
```

Comment: Consider using `' * '` as the separator, and working with a simple list of integers instead.

Comment: E.g., `' * '.join(map(str, range(1, 6))) == '1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5'`.

Comment: slightly modifying your code: `for j in range(n,0,-1): print('*'.join(map(str,range(1,j+1))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the print function's sep= parameter to avoid having to convert the numbers to string and manipulating a list:

```
n=5
for j in range(n):
    print(*range(1,n-j+1),sep=' * ')
```

- with j iterating from 0 to n-1, `range(1,n-j+1)` will produce a list of numbers that is progressively shorter:

  - when j is 0: [1,2,3,4,5] *because (n-j+1 = 6)*
  - when j is 1: [1,2,3,4]   *because (n-j+1 = 5)*
  - ...
  - when j is 4: [1]         *because (n-j+1 = 2)*
- `*range(1,n-j+1)` unpacks the values to pass them as arguments to the print function, as if you had done print(1,2,3,..., sep=' * ').
- the `sep=' * '` parameter of the print function will use the supplied string to separate printed values instead of a single space (which is its default)

Comment: : Not getting your logic can you elaborate why *range ... what it actually does and your logic can you descrive step by step

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got:

```
n=5
l = [ str(i)  for i in range(1,n+1) ]
for _ in range(1,n+1):
  print(' * '.join(l))
  del l[-1:]
```

I essentially just removed the star in the list and used it as a separator.